# Is it possible to retrieve the language tag variable in html?

Tags: html, variables, programming-languages

I would like to retrieve in my webpage the following variable:

```
<html lang="en">
```

is it a way to access that variable later on in the code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To use it in what code?

Comment: @MarkS any dynamic language which is server sided.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using jQuery.  For example, this works using jQuery 1.10.2:

```
var lang = $("html").prop("lang");
```

Comment: no way for rendering it in a server sided web page as a jsp?

Answer (score 0):

In vanilla JS, you would do it like this:

```
document.documentElement.getAttribute("lang")
```

Answer (score 0):

The code that you posted is HTML. HTML is output of parsed code  in (for example) php. If you ask to use html attribute its not possible directly in way you probably want. I.E. you can read value in javascript and send it to php script by ajax, but i guess it is not what you need.

However, as I said html is output of parsed script, so you can use variable that will hold lang value for you, and than you can use it in your script and transfer it to your html template. 
Simple example in php:

```
$lang = "en" // variable that you are free to use

if ($lang == "en") {
 // ... do something
}
// rest of your code ..
// and lets say you finally get to your html template:
echo '<html language="'.$lang.'">';
```

I am not really sure if it is what you need because you question is not detailed, but this is ho server side scripts work, hope it will help you to get the idea.